# Convex combination of semi-algebraic sets

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, convex-geometry, semialgebraic-geometry

Suppose we are given two semi-algebraic sets $S_1$ and $S_2$. Define
$$
S=\{s=ps_1+(1-p)s_2: s_1\in S_1, s_2\in S_2, 0\leq p\leq 1.\}
$$
$S$ is semi-algebraic.
Can we bound the degree of $S$?

If we have more than two semi-algebraic sets $S_1,\cdots,S_n$, can be bound the degree of their convex combination?